# Transaction cancelled but bitcoin was not return back to my wallet

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I made a transaction on 2017-05-04 04:40:52  to  39j2nuZWr4F2hZ5wYDwQwZWzsTJC4H6ujn and my transaction was on pending till today and i got a message today Sun, May 28, 2017 at 4:20 AM that my transaction was cancelled but my bitcoin was not return to my bitcoin wallet account, i want to know what is going and i will appreciate you help, thank you

Answer (score 2):

While your transaction may have been cancelled by whatever system you used, you have to wait for it to cancel out everywhere else too.

Since you only provided a destination wallet and not the actual transaction ID, it's hard to provide much info. I do, however, see transactions going to the wallet you specified above without issue. It does look like your fee (8.93 sat/B on a 224byte trans) was well below a reasonable fee to be processed in a decent amount of time on the transactions that show up though..

I suggest leveraging https://bitcoinfees.21.co/ to ensure your transactions process in a decent amount of time in the future. Relying on a cancellation is unreliable.

To see your transaction ids, check the following links

https://blockchain.info/address/39j2nuZWr4F2hZ5wYDwQwZWzsTJC4H6ujn
https://blockexplorer.com/address/39j2nuZWr4F2hZ5wYDwQwZWzsTJC4H6ujn

you will notice the transaction IDs under the heading "transactions"

Comment: Thank you and what is the transaction ID you ask, i cant see it here to provide it to you and what can i do to get my bitcoin back to my wallet

Comment: i added some more details to my post, ref: transaction id

Comment: I dont know the transaction and it not stated here but here the ref id to the address to sent it to DZm4NbdvlO